# C++ STL-like doubly linked list with constant time splicing

Tags: c++, time, linked-list, constants

I'm looking for a C++ implementation of a doubly linked list with constant time splicing. To be more specific:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice

I need the third overload to be done in constant time, too.

I understand this means that `size()` will be linear which I'm OK with as I really need cutting to be constant at all times and don't particularly need fast `size()` queries.

Is there such an implementation? I tried to search for it but haven't found anything. The more STL-like the implementation is, the better.

Thanks.

Comment: If you as the programmer know how many elements are being spliced (which you might be able to figure out as you walk the list for the iterators) then the Boost.Container `list` has [a constant-time `splice` overload](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/container/extended_functionality.html#container.extended_functionality.constant_time_range_splice).

Comment: Why do you need this? What  is your use case?

Comment: Such requests are off-topic on SO. But you can check Boost.Intrusive - `boost::intrusive::list`.